# Add two button in Firebase in App Messaging

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-in-app-messaging

Is it possible to add two buttons in Firebase `in-app-messaging`? Because I only see one button field. Is there any way to customise Firebase `in-app-messaging` to have two buttons? Thank you!

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/customize-messages#modify_message_displays

Comment: There's no documentation about how to make two buttons

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/customize-messages#create_your_own_message_display_library they allow you to use your own rendering by creating `FIRInAppMessagingRendering`